# Ordenar por count(*) en una subconsulta sql

Tags: sql, plsql

Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
      SELECT *
      FROM PERSONA
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM INVENTOR
                    WHERE PERSONA.DNI=INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*),DNI_INVENTOR
                            FROM AYUDANTE
                            WHERE INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR=AYUDANTE.DNI_INVENTOR
                            GROUP BY DNI_INVENTOR
                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC));
```

Tengo que sacar los datos de los inventores que tienen mas ayudantes. Y no se que estoy haciendo mal. Agradecería una ayuda gracias.

Añado una descripción de las tablas: https://prnt.sc/131dytd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta está sacando las personas que son inventores que tienen ayudantes, pero en ningún caso estás obteniendo la cantidad de ayudantes que tiene cada uno ni entonces te sirve para ordenar nada.

Esto se puede ver en los exists.

Este exists

```sql
EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*),DNI_INVENTOR
                            FROM AYUDANTE
                            WHERE INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR=AYUDANTE.DNI_INVENTOR
                            GROUP BY DNI_INVENTOR
                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Te devuelve los que inventores que hay grabados en la tabla ayudante. Te daría igual poner

```
    FROM AYUDANTE 
   WHERE INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR = AYUDANTE.DNI_INVENTOR
```

porque siempre existirá aunque el count() diera 0.

Si lo que quieres es una lista de inventores por número de ayudantes ordenado por el número de ayudantes podrías hacer algo así:

```sql
SELECT PERS.DNI,
         PERS.NOMBRE,
         PERS.APE1,
         PERS.APE2,
         PERS.DIR,
         PERS.TEL,
         PERS.TIPO,
         COUNT(AY.DNI_AYUDANTE) AYUDANTES
FROM PERSONA PERS
INNER JOIN INVENTOR INV
    ON INV.DNI_INVENTOR = PERS.DNI
INNER JOIN AYUDANTE AY
    ON AY.DNI_INVENTOR = INV.DNI_INVENTOR
GROUP BY  PERS.DNI, PERS.NOMBRE, PERS.APE1, PERS.APE2, PERS.DIR, PERS.TEL, PERS.TIPO
ORDER BY  COUNT(AY.DNI_AYUDANTE) DESC
```

Y si quieres el que más ayudantes tienes puedes hacerlo a partir de esta consulta de dos modos:

- Como subconsulta obteniendo el máximo de la anterior y quitando el order by
- Aprovechando la anterior y obteniendo el de de rownum = 1 (En Oracle)

Ojo, la consulta no la he probado, puede haber algún error  sintáctico

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la respuesta es valida y funciona, pero no controlo el tema de los inner joins, utilizo IN o EXISTS.  Intentaré traspasar tu respesta a eso gracias.

Comment: Puedes cambiar los inner join por FROM PERSONA, INVENTOR, AYUDANTE WHERE PERSONA.DNI = INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR AND AYUDANTE.DNI_INVENTOR = INVENTOR.DNI_INVENTOR y así igual lo entiendes mejor

Answer (score 0):

- Primero tienes que obtener la máxima cantidad de ayudantes de todos los inventores.
- Luego obtienes los DNI de aquellos inventores cuya cantidad de ayudantes sea la máxima.
- Luego buscas la información de cada invetor en PERSONA usando el DNI.

MySql:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONA
WHERE DNI IN (SELECT a.DNI_INVENTOR
              FROM AYUDANTE a
              GROUP BY a.DNI_INVENTOR
              HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*)
                                 FROM AYUDANTE a
                                 GROUP BY a.DNI_INVENTOR
                                 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
                                 LIMIT 1));
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONA
WHERE DNI IN (SELECT a.DNI_INVENTOR
              FROM AYUDANTE a
              GROUP BY a.DNI_INVENTOR
              HAVING count(*) = (SELECT MAX(count(*))
                                 FROM AYUDANTE a
                                 GROUP BY a.DNI_INVENTOR));
```

Comment: Da un error de paréntesis derecho en la linea 9, por cierto para que sirve el limit 1 en este caso. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Que raro, revisa los nombres de las tablas y campos. Yo la he probado [aquí](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95de6fb6b89200f9332e24bc38ba389d) y funciona. De nada @Daniel!

Comment: @nachospie fallo mio es la version oracle 11g :S

Comment: El `LIMIT` sirve para limitar la cantidad de registros que retorna la query, en este caso retornará solo 1 (la cantidad mayor de ayudantes de un inventor).

Comment: @Daniel tagueaste la pregunta como MySql.

Comment: si cierto mi error ya esta corregido

Comment: @Daniel ahí agregué la query para Oracle.

Comment: Esta respuesta ya da resultado pero da solo 1 linea y tengo que sacar todos los ayudantes. Y si quito el max, da un error porque devolver mas de una linea.

Comment: Pediste: "Tengo que sacar los datos de los inventores que tienen mas ayudantes" (eso retorna mi query), entonces está mal formulada la pregunta. Tendrías que reformular la pregunta para que sepamos que es realmente lo que quieres.

Comment: como tu has dicho inventores, es decir que no solo uno, la tuya devuelve solo 1, el inventor que mas ayudantes tiene

Comment: Claro, porque solo 1 es el que tiene mas ayudantes, si revisas el [ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95de6fb6b89200f9332e24bc38ba389d) que te pase para MySql verás que retorna 2, porque en mi ejemplo hay dos que tienen mas ayudantes.

Comment: yo te estoy hablando de la version de oracle que has adjuntado. La version de mysql esta de cine, pero me hace falta de la oracle que ya lo he corregido hace tiempo en las etiquetas.

Comment: Aquí tienes el [ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=317ac5886631f810cc5a1c101d2b948e) para Oracle para que ves que funciona igual. Trae 2 inventores (que son los que tienen mas ayudantes).

Comment: @naschospiu no se que estamos haciendo diferente https://prnt.sc/131hfwg . Igualmente gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Revisa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Deberías proveer un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). También sería de utilidad que compartieras un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: Viendo la foto que subiste, la cantidad máxima de ayudantes por inventor es 4, y hay un solo inventor con 4 ayudantes (DNI terminado en 27Y), por lo que la query funciona según lo solicitado en la pregunta.